# Regular Expression + Options in MongoDB (C# Driver)

Tags: c#, regex, database, mongodb

I'm working with the MongoDB driver for C # and I'm making queries to get from a collection a list of items that match a field.

I am using the BsonRegularExpression object with the following expression:

```
"/.*" + summonerName + "/"
```

This would be the equivalent of LIKE in Sql, but the problem comes when I want it to be case insensitive.
To do so, many sites comment that it must be like this:

```
BsonRegularExpression expReg = new BsonRegularExpression("/.*" + summonerName + "/", "i");
```

When I put the options parameter like this: "i" after the expression, it just doesn't return anything.

I leave the entire code here:

```
public static List<Summoner> GetSummonerByName(String summonerName)
    {
        try
        {
            var database = dbClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Summoner>(collectionSummoner);

            String nombreRegex = "";
            var nombreChar = summonerName.ToCharArray();
            foreach(Char caracter in nombreChar)
            {
                nombreRegex += "*";
                nombreRegex += caracter;
            }

            //var filter = Builders<Summoner>.Filter.Regex(u => u.name, new BsonRegularExpression("/.*C*o*r*b*a*n/"));
            BsonRegularExpression expReg = new BsonRegularExpression("/.*" + summonerName + "/");
            var filter = Builders<Summoner>.Filter.Regex(u => u.name, expReg);

            var resultado = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

            if(resultado.Count() == 0)
            {
                InsertSummoner(RiotApiConnectorService.GetSummonerByName(summonerName));
                GetSummonerByName(summonerName);
            }

            return resultado;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Has anyone experience using regular expressions in the mongo driver in C #?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `new BsonRegularExpression(Regex.Escape(summonerName), "i")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now is working, but the like operator is missing. How can i add LIKE operator from SQL in Regex.Escape?

Comment: What do you mean by "add LIKE"? `LIKE` is not a regex operator, you do not need it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i mean, the equivalent LIKE operator from SQL in Regex, something like this %SummonerName%

Comment: You need no `%` here because regex finds partial matches (it does not need to match the whole string).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i feel so dumb, thanks you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define it as

```cs
BsonRegularExpression expReg = new BsonRegularExpression(Regex.Escape(summonerName), "i")
```

The point here is that `BsonRegularExpression` regex definition should not include regex delimiters, `/` in your case. The regex instantiation is performed using the `BsonRegularExpression` class, and the regex delimiters are simply redundant, and are treated here as literal `/` in the pattern. There are no matches because your data have no slashes.

Next, you do not need `.*` here because regex searches for a match anywhere in the input text, it does not require a full string match (as is the case with `LIKE` operator).

Note `Regex.Escape(summonerName)` is used just in case there are special regex metacharacters in the `summonerName`, and if the method is not used, the search may fail.